# Ios retrieving data from sqlite database to tableview controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I need help with this since I couldn't find any on the Internet yet

I have a database with a table called halls and it has these fields(id, name,capacity,location, images phonenumber)

I couldn't figure out a way to populate my table view controller cells with the content of that table. I need each cell to display the name and the location of a hall! I'm using objective c. Please help

code I've used, for some reason I couldn't post the code itself it comes up messy here so here are some images of it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrb8g.jpg

when I run the simulator my tableview controller doesn't show any of the cells by the way its just empty and I cant figure out why

Comment: what code you tried so far?

Comment: The internet is a big place. See this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app).  By the way, i got there by following the links suggested when i tried to ask your questions **as is** on SO.

Comment: I updated with images of code

Answer (score 0):

You should take two label on `tableview cell`. you can fetch array from database. if you don't have idea about sqlite integration in ios then refer this two tutorials [Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/)  and  [Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sqlite_database.htm).

By this array you can set number of row in tableview as array.count and you can use that array in `cellforrowatindexpath` to set both cell labels which you have taken to display name and location.

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Hallcell *cell = (Hallcell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    Hall *hall = [thehalls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = hall.HName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = hall.HLocation;

    return cell;
}
```

Also check your `theHalls` array size. May be your array is empty.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks man,I tried it still nothing in the tableview controller though